# Validate and resolve a URL in express.js during redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a small link shortener service, where I store the original URL inputted from the user and I give it a short id. When I was redirecting the request like res.redirect("google.com"), I noticed that it was taking as a relative path and it was redirecting to localhost:3000/google.com. When I put the protocol such as "https", it works.

Now is there any libraries I can use to resolve a URL such as `google.com` into `https://wwww.google.com`?
What's the best way to handle this?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research.  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: A simple `if` should solve your issue

Comment: can you try to prepend double slash // ?